# How do I properly pass html in a json encoded array?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I attempting to pass a value and a string of html from php to jquery by doing the following in php:

```
// return the group id and the html
$response = array("grp_leader"=>$group_leader, "grp_html"=>$leader_html);

// return the html  
$return_html = json_encode($response);
```

My client side code is doing the following:

```
       $.post('./group_mgt.php', {function:'edit_grp', group_id:group_id}, function(data) {
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            // save the original group leader in a global var
            old_group_leader = response.grp_leader;

            // display the edit dialog
            $('#edit_grp_dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Edit Group');
            $('#edit_grp_dialog').response.grp_html.dialog('open');
```

However upon return to the client side, I am getting the group id correctly, but my code then breaks on the last line.

I went into the browser debugger and the response.grp_html is set.  However, the instruction to display the does not work.  Then the dialog open command fails as undefined is not an object....

Clearly I am not coding something properly with regard to json encode / decode, but not sure what it is.  Please let me know what I am missing.

The html does work if I do not pass back in an array and do not json encode it.  But then I am not passing back the other item.

Comment: `$('#edit_grp_dialog').response.grp_html.dialog('open');` doesn't seem to be right. What are you trying to do on `$('#edit_grp_dialog')`?

Comment: Give me an example of what `grp_html` is, and what `$('#edit_grp_dialog')`. I assume you're trying to match some element inside of `$('#edit_grp_dialog')` and trying to open that?

Comment: This code has all worked and the html displayed properly until I attempted to pass it back as a json encoded array.  Not sure what giving you more will help answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This last line is completely wrong

```
$('#edit_grp_dialog').response.grp_html.dialog('open');
```

This says that `.response` is a function or property of `$('#edit_grp_dialog')` which it is not.  SO that should simply be

```
$('#edit_grp_dialog').dialog('open');
```

Now the rest the only logical thing is that `$('#edit_grp_dialog')` exists and is initialized outside of the post. Then after the post (in the callback) you modify and open the dialog. (correct?)

So

```
 $.post('./group_mgt.php', {function:'edit_grp', group_id:group_id}, function(data) {
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        // save the original group leader in a global var
        old_group_leader = response.grp_leader;
        //modify the contents of the dialog
        $('#edit_grp_dialog').html(response.grp_html);
        // modify the title of the dialog
        $('#edit_grp_dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Edit Group');
         //$('#edit_grp_dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Edit Group: '+response.grp_leader;);
         //open the dialog
        $('#edit_grp_dialog').dialog('open');
```

I added a modification to the title, in comments, the way you have it, its basically static and there really is no reason to change it to the same thing over and over (whenever the post is triggered), so it makes no sense to change that option without some kind of modification.

That said, with what little information you give on what is needed that's the best I can guess,

cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I totally missed it.  To many hours of straight coding and being too tired to see my own mistake.  Your solution of  $('#edit_grp_dialog').html(response.grp_html); did the trick.  My actual line of code should have been $('#edit_grp_dialog').html(response.grp_html).dialog('open');  I was missing the .html   Thanks Again